# Creating bash app for OpenWrt

Tags: bash, openwrt

I would like to know how to create a script in bash for OpenWrt, but having it installed like an application and with the possibility to include arguments/options when calling the app. As an example:

```
cowsay HelloWorld
```

Would return

```
 ____________
<>  HelloWorld <>
 ------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

I need to call the script from a SSH, and execute it given an id and a state for that id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between an application and a script on a filesystem level. Arguments are processed within scripts and binaries, and there is nothing special about the file on disk that indicates the arguments it accepts.

In order to make it so that your script can be run anywhere, you need to either move it somewhere in the PATH or add the directory that it's in to your PATH.

To check what your PATH is:

```
echo $PATH
```

To append a directory to your PATH:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/directory
```

When installing your script in the appropriate place, don't forget to make it executable:

```
chmod +x /path/to/your/script
```

As a side note, OpenWRT will not have `bash`, being designed for embedded uses. All it has is [Busybox](http://www.busybox.net/).

Comment: Actually my question was how has the script to be to parse any arguments I add after it. In other words, how can I create a script that is able to parse arguments?

Comment: @xaic in that case, either [edit] your question to remove the part about "having it installed like an application" or ask a new question.

Comment: @xaic personally I'd ask a new question, as I think my answer may still be useful to e.g. Googlers.